# Password reset routing laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The user receives the password reset  url in the email which is of format http://example.com/reset/passwordresetcode. I have a route defined for this link as

```
Route::get('reset/{code}', function(){
    return View::make('users.reset_password');
});
```

On clicking the link in the email, a view containing a `form` is rendered to reset the password. This form consists of `email`, `password` and `password confirm` fields and I plan to grab the `passwordresetcode` directly from the url. I have been able to get this `passwordresetcode` in my view.

Now to process the form `post`, I have the route defined as:

```
Route::post('reset', 'UserController@passwordReset');
```

How can I get the `passwordresetcode` in this controller action `passwordReset`? I know I can have a hidden field in my `form` to receive it on `post`, but it does not quite look the laravel way and surely there must be a better way. Kind of new to laravel :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden input where you pass the code from your controller method to the view and this way the code will be posted with the rest of your form data to passwordReset on submit.

```
{{ Form::hidden('passwordresetcode', $passwordresetcode) }}
```

Or you could use a flash variable to temporarily store it in the session:

```
Session::flash('passwordresetcode', 'value');
```

And in your next controller method (passwordReset), simply retrieve it:

```
Session::get('passwordresetcode');
```

You can [read more about flash variables](http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data) in the official documentation.

Comment: I was thinking along the same way of hidden input, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it via route.

Comment: If you wanted to do it via a route, you could use `Redirect::route('route.name')->with('passwordresetcode', 'value')->with('postData', Input::all());` within the passwordReset method after you receive the post data but I wouldn't advise using a redirect when it's not necessary and there's no real benefit in this case. You'd in fact be making a user suffer even longer load time due to the redirect.

Comment: I was talking about the route in the first hand case Route::post('reset', 'UserController@passwordReset'); The way you suggested assumes I already have the passwordresetcode. In that case using route is of course useless.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the route defined for the `post` to

```
Route::post('reset/{code}', 'UserController@passwordReset');
```

did the trick. And in the controller, I can get the `passwordresetcode` by doing

```
public function passwordReset($code)
{ 
      echo $code;
}
```

However if the validation fails, trying to redirect like

```
return Redirect::route('reset/'.$code)->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validation)
                ->with('title', 'resetrequestfailure')
                ->with('message', 'Seems like you made some errors.');
```

seems not to work. I tried using the `named routes` as well, that too did not work.